# mongoose , How to create a new item in an array if dose not exist and if it exists replace the item with the new entry

Tags: mongoose

Here is the object to be updated or inserted in case it does not exist:

```
Users: {
email : 'some email'
items: [
{id: 'id1', name: 'name'},{id: 'id2', name: 'name'} ]
}
I wan
```

t to replace the items entry if exist with a new one or create a new entry in case doese not exist. thanks very much

I do not know the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by doing this;

```
let user_id = "123";
let item_name = "item Name";
let count = await Users.countDocuments({ user_id: user_id, "items.name": item_name });
```

1-  Check condition if document exists then update its value

2-  Else push object in array

```
if (count > 0) {
  await YourSchema.updateOne(
    { _id: user_id, "item.name": item_name }
  );
} 
else {
  await YourSchema.updateOne(
    { _id: user_id },
    { $push: { items: { name: item_name } } }
  );
}
```